# How to treat the SKPaymentTransactionObserver events in my iOS App if I previously need my user to be logged up and logged in

Tags: ios, in-app-subscription

Some time ago, I developed and published an iOS App in which I offer subscriptions that I validate on server side.

On server side I correctly register the access privileges of a user according to the subscription that server receive from the App (Apple Store). First server validating the receipt from the App with the Apple Store and check everything is correct.

Before presenting the list of subscriptions in the App the user must register and log in and then choose a subscription. The user's email is sent to the server along with their purchase receipt. We need user email to identify the user in our database and assign the subscription.

We now need to add to the App processing OFFER CODES that a user may have redeemed at the Apple Store, outside of the App.

Apple advises to create the SKPaymentTransactionObserver at the beginning of the App startup to receive these possible subscriptions from outside the App.

But if my App needs the user to be registered and logged in, that event could arrive from the payment queue (PaymentQueue) but since the user is not logged in, the purchase cannot be assigned.

I've been searching for a long time and I'm disoriented among so much information.
Could someone who knows something guide me on the right path on how to implement these situations?
Any minimal clue that helps me continue will be very valid, someone who has already faced this, I would greatly appreciate it.